# Website or database to find local coffee beans

Tags: coffee-shop

I'm having a problem finding places that sell bulk coffee beans (other than one grocery store selling stale beans). Is there a website somewhere that keeps track or a place I can go to ask? I live in a metropolitan area in a county west of Cleveland. I can find places that sell beans, but they seem to be one county over and a pretty decent drive away from me. I brew up small batches and I want to go into a place and buy a handful of beans at a time to try. There use to be two coffee house chains in the area, but they stopped selling beans.

I do not want to mail order beans.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a website or database really that keeps track of this.  Use google to search 'coffee roastery near me' or something similar.  Look up local coffee shops (non chain shops) and ask them where they get their beans.

Don't completely exclude mail order!!  I am based in Broken Arrow, OK but we roast our beans to order and so if you were to order coffee from my company, you would have it in your hands maybe 4-5 days after roasting which very well could be better than you might get at a local roastery.  We pride ourselves on freshness and quality so will throw away or donate coffee that has sat on the shelf for any appreciable period of time.  I am sure that we are not the only company that is this dedicated to freshness.  In addition, most roasterys have to give some sort of free shipping in order to compete in the online market space so depending on the size of your order, it very well may not cost more per pound than a local roastery.  My profile should have a link to my website if you are so inclined as to take a look around.  I typically don't link, but figured it is a direct solution to the question so it makes sense.

Last little thought.. my company started with me being in a very similar situation to you.  I wanted fresh premium coffee, and wanted to try a lot of different options.  This led me to home roasting.  This may be another option for you, but it is definitely a time and money commitment.

Comment: To hone the suggestion a bit, use Google Maps with "coffee roaster".  This turns up all the local roasters I know about (from shopping in the grocery stores), though it will also pick up several local coffee shops (some of which do indeed have a nearby roasting business).